# Funcion de Ocultar boton con JQuery

Tags: jquery

Como hago para pasar esto a **jQuery**

```
id="btn_submit" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('btn_submit').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Es para ocultar o bloquear un botón temporalmente para evitar el doble submit de un formulario, ¿Hay alguna otra manera de evitarlo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Básicamente al hacer **click** al id *btn_submit*
 le cambia la propiedad **CSS** *visibility* a *hidden*

Se le agrega un tiempo de 2 segundos con setTimeout()

```
  $("#btn_submit").on('click',function(){ //Evento Click
     $("#btn_submit").css('visibility', 'hidden'); //Cambio de propiedad CSS
     setTimeout(function(){ //Se aguardan los milisegundos marcados en la próxima linea
       $("#btn_submit").css('visibility', 'visible');
     }, 2000); //2000 milisegundos == 2 segundos
   });
```

Aqui tienes mas sobre setTimeout https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Como podria ponerle un tiempo de al menos unos 2 segundos para que vuelva a aparecer?

Comment: O cuando ya se haya enviado la peticion al servidor

Comment: Oye Luciando Muchas gracias hoy me has resuelto muchas dudas

Comment: Ahora te edito la respuesta.

Comment: pesima y ineficiente solucion yo lo aria con un `setTimeout(function(){ //Se aguardan los milisegundos marcados en la proxima linea
       $("#btn_submit").css('visibility', 'visible');
     }, 2000); `

Comment: De acuerdo con @andygibbs equivoque de funcion, en tanto así la descripción era del setTimeout() Gracias!

Comment: me imagine que te equivocaste ya que un programador experimentado pocas veces usas setInterval() a menos que sea necesariamente requerido

Comment: A todo esto algun curso que me recomienden para apredener JavaScript y luego JQuery?

Comment: Y en Youtube buscar alguno y luego tu investigar de manera personal.

Answer (score 2):

no entendi bien lo de el doble submit pero aqui te dejo un codigo para hacer lo que quieres con jquery:

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function(){ //le decimos cuando hagas click ejecute una funccion anonima

  $(this).hide(); //y que oculte este elemento clickeado

 $(this).css("visivility","0"); //o si quieres darle simplemente una visivilidad 0 seria asi
})
```

Comment: Si eso esta bien, por ejemplo cuando le doy Guardar a mi formulario a veces el servidor tarda en responder entonces pueda ser que el Usuario le de clic 3 veces y eso me pasa, cuando veo en la BD se duplica o triplica los datos enviados por el formulario como puedo evitar eso? dentro de esa misma funcion de jQuery?

Comment: podrias poner tu codigo a ver que estas haciendo mal ?

Comment: ok permiteme lo pongo ahora

Comment: Podrías poner esto en la descripción de la pregunta, así no se pierde en los comentarios.